# write and read string to binary file C++

Tags: c++, string, file, malloc

Im having problems writing string into a binary file. This is my code:

```
ofstream outfile("myfile.txt", ofstream::binary);
std::string text = "Text";
outfile.write((char*) &text, sizeof (string));
outfile.close();
```

Then, I try to read it,

```
char* buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(string));
ifstream infile("myfile.txt", ifstream::binary);    
infile.read(buffer, sizeof (prueba));
std::string* elem = (string*) buffer;
cout << *elem;
infile.close();
```

I just cant get it to work. I am sorry, I am just desperate. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you're writing the string object data, but that probably doesn't write the the TEXT stored in the object.  You should be using Streams in C++.   The equivalent to outfile << text.

Comment: @Mark a quick search revealed: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: Post some real, copy-pasted code, please. Assuming `string` is `std::string`, this won't compile: `string *text = "Text";
`

Comment: There is a lot wrong here, in basic understanding of how C++ works. You seem like a C programmer who's trying to make C++ things work. You should stop and read a book on C++. And most importantly, realize that C++ is a different animal (one you should almost never use `malloc` with).

Comment: Does this even compile? : `string* test = "Text";` http://ideone.com/TcqhP

Comment: @hmjd: No, it doesn't. Any compiler that accepts it is broken beyond repair.

Comment: @BillJames - "a quick search" does not help here, as this `string` could be anything, not necessarily `std::string`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ - properly writing std::string to binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27523273/c-properly-writing-stdstring-to-binary-file)

Answer (score 13):

To write a std::string to a binary file, you need to save the string length first:

```
std::string str("whatever");
size_t size=str.size();
outfile.write(&size,sizeof(size));
outfile.write(&str[0],size);
```

To read it in, reverse the process, resizing the string first so you will have enough space:

```
std::string str;
size_t size;
infile.read(&size, sizeof(size));
str.resize(size);
infile.read(&str[0], size);
```

Because strings have a variable size, unless you put that size in the file you will not be able to retrieve it correctly. You could rely on the '\0' marker that is guaranteed to be at the end of a c-string or the equivalent string::c_str() call, but that is not a good idea because

1. you have to read in the string character by character checking for the null
2. a std::string can legitimately contain a null byte (although it really shouldn't because calls to c_str() are then confusing).

Comment: This worked for me with one change. In the writing code, I changed outfile.write(&str[0],size); to outfile.write(str.c_str(),size);

Answer (score 12):

the line

```
outfile.write((char*) &text, sizeof (string));
```

is not correct

`sizeof(string)` doesn't return the length of the string, it returns the sizeof the string type in bytes.

also do not cast text to `char*` using a C cast, you can get hold of the char* by using the appropriate member function `text.c_str()`

you can simply write

```
outfile << text;
```

instead.

Answer (score 3):

- Why are you using pointers to `std::string` class?
- You should not use `sizeof` with `std::string`, as it returns the size of the `std::string` object, and not the real size of the string inside.

You should try:

```
string text = "Text";
outfile.write(text.c_str(), text.size());
```

or

```
outfile << text;
```

Answer (score 1):

Should probably also use `c_str()` to get the char pointer too, instead of that straight crazy cast.

Comment: Assuming it *is* `std::string`. The `string` is being used in a pretty weird way.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong wrong way you are using to write & read the file
and file extension error you are trying to read text file `.txt`
correct code

**Write to file**

```
std::string text = "Text";
ofstream outfile("myfile.dat", ofstream::binary | ios::out);
outfile.write(&text,sizeof (string));//can take type
outfile.write(&text,sizeof (text));//can take variable name
outfile.close();
```

**reading file**

```
char* buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(string));
ifstream infile("myfile.dat", ifstream::binary | ios::in);    
infile.read(buffer, sizeof (prueba));
std::string* elem = (string*) buffer;
cout << *elem;
infile.close();
```

Try This it will work

Comment: We appreciate your answer but this is a 5 year old question.

Comment: @Sandeesh I think this shouldn't matter as long as the answer is in a "okay-ish" format, which it is, from my point of view

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found the perfect answer here: [Write file in binary format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43602649/write-file-in-binary-format/43602935#43602935)

Key issues: use string::length to get the length of the string when writing out and use resize() before reading the string. And both for reading and writing, use mystring.c_str() instead the string itself.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code snippet.

```
/* writing string into a binary file */

  fstream ifs;
  ifs.open ("c:/filename.exe", fstream::binary | fstream::in | fstream::out);

  if (ifs.is_open())
  {
   ifs.write("string to binary", strlen("string to binary")); 
   ifs.close();
  }
```

[Here](http://cplus.about.com/od/learning1/ss/random_2.htm) is a good example.