# After writing a structure into a binary file, the file still has normal characters instead of unreadable ones

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, binary-data, file-writing

I'm trying to write a structure to a binary file. The structure consists of strings and integers. If there were no strings I'd just take the entire object and write it to the binary file normally, but if I do that now, the string can be read easily as well.

So I decided to write each of the attribute of the structure separately. I was working with the strings [the same way like it's mentioned in this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10873443/9515245).

This is the main function that is supposed to save the structure into the **name.bin** file.

```cpp
void saveFileBin(std::string nameOfFile) {
    Person people[SIZE_OF_ARRAY] =
    {Person("Name1", "lastName2", Address("Street1", "City1", "111"), Date(1, 1, 1111)),
    Person("Name2", "lastName2", Address("Street2", "City2", "222"), Date(2, 2, 2222)),
    Person("Name3", "lastName3", Address("Street3", "City3", "333"), Date(3, 3, 3333))};

    std::ofstream myFile(nameOfFile + ".bin", std::ios::binary);
    if (myFile.is_open())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; i++)
        {
            people[i].write(&myFile);
        }
        myFile.close();

        std::cout << "The entire thing is in memory";
    }
    else 
    {
        throw std::exception("Unable to open file");
    }
};
```

and this is a function for writing each attribute into the file.

```cpp
void Person::write(std::ofstream* out)
{
    out->write(_name.c_str(), _name.size());
    out->write(_lastName.c_str(), _lastName.size());
    out->write(_residence.getStreet().c_str(), _residence.getStreet().size());
    out->write(_residence.getZip().c_str(), _residence.getZip().size());
    out->write(_residence.getCity().c_str(), _residence.getCity().size());
    std::string day = std::to_string(_birthDate.getDay());
    std::string month = std::to_string(_birthDate.getMonth());
    std::string year = std::to_string(_birthDate.getYear());
    out->write(day.c_str(), day.size());
    out->write(month.c_str(), month.size());
    out->write(year.c_str(), year.size());
}
```

The resulting file has everything in plain text readable.
Though if I instead in the main method call `myFile.write((char*)people, sizeof(people));` then it shows up unreadable characters correctly but string variables are still normally read. That's why I went with converting into the string all variables and then writing it to a bin file altogether.

How come my method still shows all strings like it's not even binary file? Even though I have std::ios::binary as a parameter?

The output file contains this:

```
Name1lastName1Street11111City11111111Name2lastName2Street22222City22222222Name3lastName3Street33333City3333333
```

Whereas if I write the entire structure into the binary file, it looks like this:

```
     lÊ87  Name1 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ              à^Ê87  lastName1 ÌÌÌÌÌÌ                  Ð_Ê87  Street1 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ              ÐdÊ87  City1 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ               bÊ87  111 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ                    W  ÌÌÌÌ`kÊ87  Name2 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ              fÊ87  lastName2 ÌÌÌÌÌÌ                 €iÊ87  Street2 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ              PbÊ87  City2 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ              ÐiÊ87  222 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ                    ®  ÌÌÌÌ€dÊ87  Name3 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ               `Ê87  lastName3 ÌÌÌÌÌÌ                p`Ê87  Street3 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ               gÊ87  City3 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ              ðbÊ87  333 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ                    
  ÌÌÌÌ lÊ87  Name1 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ              à^Ê87  lastName1 ÌÌÌÌÌÌ                Ð_Ê87  Street1 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ              ÐdÊ87  City1 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ               bÊ87  111 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ                    W  ÌÌÌÌ`kÊ87  Name2 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ              fÊ87  lastName2 ÌÌÌÌÌÌ                 €iÊ87  Street2 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ              PbÊ87  City2 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ              ÐiÊ87  222 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ                    ®  ÌÌÌÌ€dÊ87  Name3 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ               `Ê87  lastName3 ÌÌÌÌÌÌ                p`Ê87  Street3 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ               gÊ87  City3 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ              ðbÊ87  333 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ                    
  ÌÌÌÌ lÊ87  Name1 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ              à^Ê87  lastName1 ÌÌÌÌÌÌ                Ð_Ê87  Street1 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ              ÐdÊ87  City1 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ               bÊ87  111 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ                    W  ÌÌÌÌ`kÊ87  Name2 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ              fÊ87  lastName2 ÌÌÌÌÌÌ                 €iÊ87  Street2 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ              PbÊ87  City2 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ              ÐiÊ87  222 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ                    ®  ÌÌÌÌ€dÊ87  Name3 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ               `Ê87  lastName3 ÌÌÌÌÌÌ                p`Ê87  Street3 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ               gÊ87  City3 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ              ðbÊ87  333 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ                    
  ÌÌÌÌ
```

EDIT:
As requested here is a header for Person.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H
#include <string.h>
#include "Address.h"
#include "Date.h"
#include <fstream>

struct Person {
public:
    Person(std::string name, std::string last_name, Address _residence, Date birthDate);
    Person();
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Person& p);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Person& p);
    std::string getName() const { return _name; }
    std::string getLastName() const { return _lastName; };
    Address getResidence() const { return _residence; };
    Date getDate() const { return _birthDate; };
    void read(std::ifstream *in);
    void write(std::ofstream *out);
private:
    std::string _name;
    std::string _lastName;
    Address _residence;
    Date _birthDate;
};
#endif // !PERSON_H
```

Comment: Character `A` is represented internally by its ASCII code 65. Writing a string into a binary file, the bytes of the string will be written. Looking with a text editor into this binary file, the bytes will be interpreted as characters again i.e. the byte with value 65 becomes an `A` again. Whatever you thought binary is, it's just binary but nothing encrypted. Have a look into an `.exe` file. Even there, you will find some portions of readable text (probably).

Comment: Btw. `out->write(_name.c_str(), _name.size());` does cover all characters but not where the string ends. Either write `_name.size() + 1` to capture the 0 terminator as well or prefix the string with writing its length (in binary).

Comment: Binary file does not means "encrypted". Btw, could you also provide the declaration of the Person class. I suspect that your write((char*)people, sizeof(people)) does not write any string to the file but only pointer to them

Comment: You will find a hard time figuring out how to read the data back in a coherent manner, given that you have not indicated where each string begins and ends in the file.

Comment: @Scheff Edited my question with the output files both for the individual variables and the whole structure. I feel like the first one which I'm attempting should not look like this, or am I wrong? The second one also has variables written normally.

Comment: @Antrophy *Whereas if I write the entire structure into the binary file* -- Let's see the structure.  As the previous comment stated, if `Person` is not trivially copyable, then writing to a binary file shouldn't be done.

Comment: You should provide the declaration of `Person` as well. How to serialize things correctly mainly depends of the type of each thing.

Comment: @Scheff added the declaration of `Person`.

Comment: I'm afraid you overestimated the meaning of `std::ios::binary`. (Not that you don't need it.) Please, have a look onto this: [Binary and text modes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c#Binary_and_text_modes)

Comment: @Antrophy -- Well that settles it -- you can't write `Person` to a binary file like that.  You class is not POD or trivially copyable.  Also think about it logically -- you probably used `sizeof(Person)` in your writing code.  If those strings contains a million characters, the `sizeof(Person)` is not going to be several million bytes.

Comment: @Antrophy [See this example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c69b26eac352ce50).  The `sizeof(Person)` is 72, regardless that `name` contains a one million character string of stars.  So using `sizeof(Person)` to specify the byte count when writing wasn't going to work.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I see, so basically the only option to write this struct into a binary file is to use the method that I custom created as shown in the question. And since it is readable by my doesn't mean anything and it is indeed a binary format, correct?

Comment: It would be better to use a library that handles that work in a consistent manner, like boost or google protobuf.  But you have the basic idea correct -- you would need to serialize each member in some way where you can recreate the `Person` object from the file when you read the file,

Answer (score 1):

A sample to serialize a `std::string` (with a limited length of ≤ 65536 characters):

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void writeString(std::ostream &out, const std::string &str)
{
  // write length of string (two bytes, little endian)
  assert(str.size() < 1 << 16);
  const size_t size = str.size();
  char buffer[2] = { (char)(size & 0xff), (char)(size >> 8 & 0xff) };
  out.write(buffer, sizeof buffer)
  // write string contents
  && out.write(str.c_str(), size);
}

void readString(std::istream &in, std::string &str)
{
  // read length
  char buffer[2];
  if (!in.read(buffer, 2)) return; // failed
  const size_t size = (unsigned char)buffer[0] | (unsigned char)buffer[1] << 8;
  // allocate size
  str.resize(size);
  // read contents
  in.read(&str[0], size);
}

int main()
{
  // sample
  std::string name = "Antrophy";
  // write binary file
  { std::ofstream out("test.dat", std::ios::binary);
    writeString(out, name);
  } // closes file
  // reset sample
  name = "";
  // read binary file
  { std::ifstream in("test.dat", std::ios::binary);
    readString(in, name);
  } // closes file
  // report result
  std::cout << "name: '" << name << "'\n";
}
```

Output:

```
name: 'Antrophy'
```

The hexdump of `test.dat`:

```
00000000  08 00 41 6e 74 72 6f 70  68 79                    |..Antrophy|
0000000a
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2aa24acb11be1e89)

**Note:**

Consider how the length (limited to 16 bit) is written. This can be done similar to serialize integral values.

---

A (IMHO) good introduction is provided by the C++FAQ:

[**Serialization and Unserialization**](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization)

---

An extended sample for binary I/O of a composed type `Person`:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

template <size_t nBytes, typename VALUE>
std::ostream& writeInt(std::ostream &out, VALUE value)
{
  const size_t size = sizeof value;
  char buffer[nBytes];
  const size_t n = std::min(nBytes, size);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    buffer[i] = (char)(value >> 8 * i & 0xff);
  }
  for (size_t i = size; i < nBytes; ++i) buffer[i] = '\0';
  return out.write(buffer, nBytes);
}

template <size_t nBytes, typename VALUE>
std::istream& readInt(std::istream &in, VALUE &value)
{
  const size_t size = sizeof value;
  char buffer[nBytes];
  if (in.read(buffer, nBytes)) {
    value = (VALUE)0;
    const size_t n = std::min(nBytes, size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      value |= (VALUE)(unsigned char)buffer[i] << 8 * i;
    }
  }
  return in;
}

void writeString(std::ostream &out, const std::string &str)
{
  // write length of string (two bytes, little endian)
  assert(str.size() < 1 << 16);
  const size_t size = str.size();
  writeInt<2>(out, size)
  // write string contents
  && out.write(str.c_str(), size);
}

void readString(std::istream &in, std::string &str)
{
  // read length
  std::uint16_t size = 0;
  if (!readInt<2>(in, size)) return; // failed
  // allocate size
  str.resize(size);
  // read contents
  in.read(&str[0], size);
}

struct Person {
  std::string lastName, firstName;
  int age;
  
  void write(std::ostream&) const;
  void read(std::istream&);
};

void Person::write(std::ostream &out) const
{
  writeString(out, lastName);
  writeString(out, firstName);
  writeInt<2>(out, age);
}

void Person::read(std::istream &in)
{
  readString(in, lastName);
  readString(in, firstName);
  std::int16_t age; assert(sizeof age == 2); // ensure proper sign extension
  if (readInt<2>(in, age)) this->age = age;
}

int main()
{
  // sample
  Person people[2] = {
    { "Mustermann", "Klaus", 23 },
    { "Doe", "John", -111 }
  };
  // write binary file
  { std::ofstream out("test.dat", std::ios::binary);
    for (const Person &person : people) person.write(out);
  } // closes file
  // read sample
  Person peopleIn[2] = {
    { "", "", -1 },
    { "", "", -1 }
  };
  // read binary file
  { std::ifstream in("test.dat", std::ios::binary);
    for (Person &person : peopleIn) person.read(in);
  } // closes file
  // report result
  int i = 1;
  for (const Person &person : peopleIn) {
    std::cout << "person " << i++ << ": '"
      << person.firstName << ' ' << person.lastName
      << ", age: " << person.age << '\n';
  }
}
```

Output:

```
person 1: 'Klaus Mustermann, age: 23
person 2: 'John Doe, age: -111
```

The hexdump of `test.dat`:

```
00000000  0a 00 4d 75 73 74 65 72  6d 61 6e 6e 05 00 4b 6c  |..Mustermann..Kl|
00000010  61 75 73 17 00 03 00 44  6f 65 04 00 4a 6f 68 6e  |aus....Doe..John|
00000020  91 ff                                             |..|
00000022
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12535a2774274490)

**Note:**

The kind of binary I/O for integral values (`readInt()` and `writeInt()`) might look overcomplicated compared to the simple `out.write((char*)value, sizeof value);` found elsewhere. I did it in a more portable way which will even work when used on different platforms with distinct endianess and/or distinct size of integrals.