# Save Data to a .DAT file

Tags: c++

I need to save data the user input to a dat file, I got a description of an item, price, quantity
my code is this, it doesn't save the data though

```
void saveInventory()
{
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("inventory.dat", ios::binary);
if(!outfile.is_open()){
    cout<<"File openning error."<<endl;
    return;
}
outfile.write((char*)&items, sizeof(items));
outfile.close();
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: A pure function with arguments and types would make it so much easier to see what you actually try to save.

Comment: still waiting for experienced user

Comment: @Scheff Sorry, I don't know what to tell you but I got to let you go

Comment: About Serialization and Deserialization (the general cases of saving and loading): there is a whole side on the C++ FAQ: [**Serialization and Unserialization**](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization) which I can warmly recommend as a start.

Comment: Unfortunately, you didn't expose how `items` is defined. (Hence, the request for a [mcve].) Say, `items` is defined as `std::vector<Item> items;` then your write will not do what you expect. The `std::vector` is a wrapper where contents is stored on heap and managed/pointed to internally. Hence, your `write()` will write this pointer only without considering the actual contents you intend to write. (Better?) ;-)

Comment: Btw. I just remembered that I already wrote an answer for a similar question. FYI: [SO: After writing a structure into a binary file, the file still has normal characters instead of unreadable ones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58752800/7478597).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to write something like:

```
    outfile.write((char*)&items[0], items.size() * sizeof(item));
```

Comment: How can you know whether this is legal or even compiles without knowing how `items` is declared?

Comment: Assuming items is a vector, as:

        outfile.write((char*)&items, sizeof(items));

does not work.